# How to refer to instance methods in documentation?

Tags: class, scala, object, methods, documentation

How can I refer to an instance field when writing documentation?

Consider this code:

```
object Foo {
  val foo = 42
}

class Foo {
  val foo = 42
}
```

In Java, one would use `Foo.foo` for the "static" method and `Foo#foo` for the instance method.

But in Scala `#` is already taken for path-dependent types and

```
class Foo {
  class foo
  def foo = 42
}
```

is legal code, so I can't refer to it unambiguously.

Is there some convention how this should look like?

Answer (score 4):

Tough. Maybe English-like, as in `Foo's foo`? I had missed the ambiguity of `#`. That is still my preferred choice, though, because the ambiguity only exists in the absence of context. When referring to a type, `#` has one meaning. When referring to a value or method, `#` has another.

Since types and methods/values do not share the namespace, I don't see the ambiguity being of relevance here.

Comment: I use # for this purpose, too.

Comment: The main problem is how should an corresponding URL linking to ScalaDoc look like? There is no way to embed "context" into an URL ... except choosing an unambiguous symbol. And if we already have to invent a symbol we can use it in the documentation, too.

Comment: @soc Well, but what does `Foo.foo` refer to in ScalaDoc? To the `type foo` in `object Foo`, or to `def foo` in `object Foo`? This problem already exists. Given it only happens if people are so crass as to name type and non-type members with the same identifier, I say we ignore it -- or solve for both. Besides... iirc, `#` in an URL has special meaning, so we can't really use it on URLs, can we?

Comment: Sure, so what would be a good solution? Looks like we have run out of symbols we can use ...